# Firebase/AngularJS nested ng-repeat with search filter issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase, angularfire, angular-filters

I've got an interesting issue when getting data from Firebase and doing a nested ng-repeat. When the first key of the second loop is not 0 the filter doesn't work.

See the below how the data is structured in Firebase. Note that question 2 doesn't contain an option with a key of 0.

`filtertest
 -- questions
   -- 1
      -- name: "question1"
         -- options
            -- 0
               -- name: "option1"
            -- 1
               -- name: "option2"
            -- 2
               -- name: "option3"
   -- 2
      -- name: "question2"
         -- options
            -- 3
               -- name: "option1"
            -- 4
               -- name: "option2"
   -- 3
      -- name: "question3"
         -- options
            -- 0
               -- name: "option1"
            -- 3
               -- name: "option3"
            -- 4
               -- name: "option4"`

The code is as follows:

```js
angular.module('myapp',['firebase'])
.controller('FirebaseController', function($scope, $firebase){

  ref = new Firebase('https://filtertest.firebaseio.com/questions');
  $scope.questions = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

  console.log($scope)

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <title>tallytab</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Firebase</h1>
    <div ng-controller="FirebaseController">
        <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
            <h2>{{ question.name }}</h2>
            <div><input ng-model="search" />
            <div ng-repeat="option in question.options | filter:search">
                {{ option.name }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <!-- Firebase -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <!-- AngularFire -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.2/angularfire.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

You will see that the options in question2 are not filterable because there is no key=0. There just needs to be a key=0. It can be followed by a key=3 and so on. The filtering of question 3 works fine.

Does anybody have an idea why this is happing? And how can I make this work? Options with key=0 may be deleted and thereby messing up my filter.

Comment: When your sequential data is missing an element at index 0, or is missing a number of other indexes, Firebase will not recognize them as an array. Kato explained it here: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: Thanks Frank, that answers most of my questions.

Comment: Please, for all that's good and pure in this world, don't use sequential, numeric ids in distributed data.

Comment: In my case Firebase is getting its data from an RDMS. Firebase is just read-only and used for 3-way binding purposes. Even if I use non-numerical keys the filter on the inner ng-repeat does not work. It shoud, right?